# When trying to use custom cursors in HTML, does the URL have to be a public URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I am trying to implement a custom cursor for a project that I am working on. Here is a certain line of code:

```
document.getElementById("theCanvas").style.cursor = new URL("./restore cursor.ico");
```

However, on the web page that I run in my browser, the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL". Whenever I go online (even looking at other stack overflow questions), everyone always uses an http or https URL when using a custom cursor. The cursor I want however, is not on a website. It is within my folder.

Now I can implement Node.js into this if necessary and make a web server out of this project, but I don't feel like doing that right now (I will if I have to). Is there any way to implement a custom cursor without the icon being on an http/https web server?

Comment: *"The cursor I want however, is not on a website. It is within my folder."* - If the cursor is only on your computer and not available on the web then how are users on the web meant to **use** it?  If you mean that you're just running your page locally by opening the file in a web browser then you're going to encounter a variety of limitations in that regard.  If the goal is to make a web page then you should start by serving that page from a server (even a local one on your workstation for development).

Comment: Yes its possible, you should provide more context as for example which library are you willing to use etc..

Comment: Instead of creating a URL object you could just assign the cursor to the CSS `"url(./restore%20cursor.ico), auto"`.

Comment: You are missing the second parameter. **If url is a relative URL, base is required, and will be used as the base URL.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL